# I'm confused why a truthful claim in a post is downvoted, and its annoying me that no one sees after numerous edits. Please help

Tags: discussion

I know there must be a communication problem. For some reason, I can't get people to realize that general sudoku is a form a of vertex covering. People have downvoted this truthful claim. I have something wrong with the post. Please give me any reasons why no is able to understand the color-code.

### Question

What do we do when we make a claim and obviously show its true and its downvoted?

here's the link

[Solving Vertex Cover Problems by solving $n^2 x n^2$ Sudoku puzzles](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/111744/solving-vertex-cover-problems-by-solving-n2-x-n2-sudoku-puzzles)

Comment: Is it the title? Is it the long post? I mean clearly I've shown that sudoku can be a vertex cover problem. I even shown the search for them is at least as hard as Sudoku. I'm not sure why proof of contradiction is frowned upon. In math this can be considered formal(a proof of contradiction).

Comment: Was it a reader expecting a conventional vertice cover? I mean a sudoku puzzle is a graph. So it can be made into a vertice cover problem. Just tag the values with lines connecting values 1s together, 2 together etc. And finding the other lines completes the vertice cover(solve the puzzle)

Comment: Seems to me there's plenty of comments already answering this question.

Answer (score 6):

> What do we do when we make a claim and obviously show its true and its downvoted?

1. A true claim doesn't make a question.
2. A question around a true claim doesn't make good SE post.
3. What's obvious to you is not always obvious to others.
4. The claim may not be true.
5. You can not do anything direct about downvotes.
6. You can incorporate the feedback given to you into your post and hope some downvoters change their mind.
7. Downvotes should probably not matter to you beyond indicating something is wrong with your post.

Comment: Yes, this is true. *What's obvious to you is not always obvious to others.* Clearly, there's a spectrum of personality and thought patterns. An incompatible thought pattern is just like another language. I can't communicate abstract thoughts in a formal matter. It doesn't mean I'm smarter or dumber. It just means there's "no-clicking." I just wish, that when I'm expected to speak or write English. That language isn't so subtle. So I created literal pictures. And, for some reason, it didn't work.(confused why) If there was a race of aliens that were clones of me. We are missing the picture.

Comment: @TravisWells If you want to talk TCS, mathematics should be your main language.

Answer (score 6):

There are some problems beyond what Raphael said:
This is not a blog, if you do more than 20 edits it is a problem on its own.
When you find that something was not obvious or omitted in the question, please, do not make partial answer in the question via numerous edits.

Proof by contradiction is not frowned upon, it is a general problem that when you have all the tools and all the knowledge and pick one proving technique, it is simply request "do that work for me, the way I have imagined", so it is no longer a question, point blank request in sugar coating.

Showing one or two examples does not constitute definition. The amount of work and time spent on your project is irrelevant, we can only work with textual description that you give us, we have no clue what you have learned and where are your difficulties and obstacles in the project. You want answers, we do not want (or like) to guess what is the question really about, incremental improvements do not work for us, at least not the way that more than 100 revisions among several questions are placed. Since this didn't help, it is a high time to change something.

This site should serve as the knowledge vault, Q&A, but there are things that are off-topic here:
Science advancements, one-on-one tutoring, too localized questions that are important only to you.

If people are not interested in your post, well, it happens, but it does not pose meta discussion thread yet.